# BizTalk BRE - Method in .Net Class not working in Orchestration Call Rule Shape

Tags: biztalk, business-rules, biztalk-2013

I am trying to use an external class library method call AddValidationErrors to errors out the data validation errors in Business Rule Composer. I have created a FactCreator class which implements IFactCreator interface also. This is working when I try to test my policy in Business Rule Composer. But when I try in Orchestration it rule is not fired. Can anyone help me out in this. Below is my code for Validation errors

```
public void AddValidationError(TypedXmlDocument activeDoc, string err)
{
   XmlDocument doc = activeDoc.Document.OwnerDocument;
   XmlNode errorRoot = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ValidationErrors");
   XmlElement newError = doc.CreateElement("Error");
   newError.InnerText = err;
   errorRoot.AppendChild(newError);
}
```

FactCreator Class:

```
    private object[] objs;

    public FactCreator()
    {

    }
    public object[] CreateFacts(RuleSetInfo ruleSetInfo)
    {
        objs = new object[1];
        objs[0] = new ValidationErrors.ValidationErrors();
        return (objs);
    }

    public Type[] GetFactTypes(RuleSetInfo ruleSetInfo)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled BRE static support for .NET?

To enable BRE support for static .Net methods these methods, add a `REG_DWORD` key named `StaticSupport`, with a value of `1` to the following registry path:

32-bit Windows

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\BusinessRules\3.0\
```

64-bit Windows

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\BusinessRules\3.0\
```

This is a one-time activity.

Above information comes from [this](https://andreikos.wordpress.com/2013/10/15/enabling-bre-support-for-static-net-methods/) blog.

MSDN extract addition:

> Another option is to put StaticSupport in the BTNTsvc[64].exe.config
>   file, as any settings here override what's in the Registry. Further,
>   one can also make the argument that this option is preferred since it
>   isolates the change in default behavior to BizTalk only, whereas
>   Registry settings are global to the Operating System.

Comment: MSDN states it can be updated via the config file as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa950269.aspx. I will update my answer.

Comment: Is this a one time activity?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the possibility of changing BTSNTSvc.exe.config or BTSNTSvc64.exe.config

Comment: I have done the second option. But still the same output,

Comment: I've never had luck doing this without updating the registry.  Restart the computer after updating it.  Should be a one time thing per server, and can be scripted out in powershell or with .reg files.